# Installshield permissions on Citrix network drive?

Tags: networking, installation, permissions, installshield, citrix

I'm using installshield express to write a simple installer. I need to set read/write/modify rights to the database directory. ( Because of Vista/Win7 users with restricted rights)

I'm setting FullControl permissions to all folders within "DATABASDIR".
( [%USERDOMAIN] [LogonUser] ).
This works fine in XP / Vista / Win 7 etc.

The problem:

When users install on Citrix, and choose a network drive (N for the database folder, the setting of permissions throws an error:

"Error while setting permissions on object "N:\PathToDBDir\Folder"
System Error: The system cannot find the path specified (3)"

But the folder is existing ... it has just been put there by the installer itself ??? Why doesn't it find the folder it wrote itself ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For who cares:

Well, seems like there's an error with MSI or Installshield or whatever ... you can't set rights on a nework folder. (all windows versions.)

Our solution was to add a custom action after all files been written, and set the folder permission yourself by calling an exe with command line params [DATABASEDIR] ...